# Javascript hide filter child innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, hide

I am trying to sort a navigation, every parent A should be hidden / invisible, except the child.innerHTML == sorttype

How can I achieve that?

```
function sort_sidebar(type) {
    if(type && type.substring(0,6) == "#sort=") {
      $('#id > div > a').hide()
      // $('#id > div > a > p:last-child > span:last-child').show() where innerHTML == type.slice(6).toUpperCase()
       history.pushState("", document.title, type)
       alert(type.slice(6).toUpperCase())
     } else {
       $('#id > div > a').show()
       history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead searching innerHTML from a children element, I gave parent element an "data-type" attribut, which is  the same as the innerHTML, to filter it

```
$('#id> div > a').hide().filter('[data-type="'+type.slice(6).toUpperCase()+'"]').show();
```